# Ruby on Rails: no such file to load -- openssl on RedHat Linux Enterprise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, rake, redhat

I am trying to do 'rake db:migrate' and getting the error message 'no such file to load -- openssl'. Both 'openssl' and 'openssl-devel' packages are installed. Others on Debian or Ubuntu seem to be able to get rid of this by installing 'libopenssl-ruby', which is not available for RedHat. Has anybody run into this and have a solution for it?

Comment: The answer is here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/136893#808492

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem on Ubuntu, after upgrading to 8.10.
The solution for Ubuntu was

`sudo apt-get install libopenssl-ruby`

Answer (score 10):

it seems you need to make the ruby header file

go into the openssl directory and:

```
ruby extconf.rb
cd ../..
make
make install
```

See [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/90083)

Comment: This answer assumes that you've compiled your own ruby binary.  The extconf.rb file is located in the ruby-X.X.X/ext/openssl/ directory.

Comment: Worked for me too, needed to install ruby1.8-dev to solve a mkmf? error though (extconf.rb:17:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)) `sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev`

Comment: You may need to specify the location of your openssl libraries (as suggested in the linked article).  I had to use `ruby extconf.rb --with-openssl-include=/usr/local/ssl/include --with-openssl-lib=/usr/local/ssl/lib`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using RVM to manage your rubies follow the directions here:

http://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a gem you are missing.  Can you provide the stack trace and the line of code where it originates?

Re-run rake with `--trace` to get the stack trace printed.

EDIT: Also what version of Ruby are you running?  openssl.rb is in my 1.8.6 install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried going into the openssl folder and running make etc but it couldnt find the libraries lcrypto. I solved the issue by running ruby 1.9.3-p327.

Hope this helps!